# Automating rake doc:app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, rdoc

For you rails programmers, what's the easiest way to keep your RDoc files up-to-date?

I know I can run `rake doc:app` manually, but I really don't feel like adding a manual step to the check-in process, and since we're already using [cruisecontrolrb](http://cruisecontrolrb.thoughtworks.com/) to handle deployment and testing automation, it seems like there should be an easy way to regenerate these files on check-in.

Is anyone already automating `rake doc:app`?  And, if so, what are your suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

How about adding it to crontabs? If you don't like the syntax, you could try using the [whenever](http://github.com/javan/whenever/tree/master) gem, which Ryan Bates' has made an excellent [Railscasts episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/164-cron-in-ruby) on.

Answer (score 1):

[Guard](https://github.com/guard/guard/) is a nice, general purpose system that watches for changes in a Rails project. Add in [the guard-rake gem](https://github.com/rubyist/guard-rake) and you can have it trigger the `rake doc:app` task whenever files change.